# How to handle OAuth Token Expiration & generation during 24 hours Endurance test in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am doing performance testing on the API's which uses OAuth Mechanism .

**Problem: **

1. Generate the token at starting of the test (AP1) & pass the token to API2.
2. Expiry of token is 12 hours.
3. Fire the token API1 at starting of the test and pass the token to API2, So I have to  re-generate the token (API1) at the mid of the test and pass the token to API2 .
4. Total Duration of Endurance test : 24 hours

Note : token generation time is not present in Generation of token API response .

Referred following blogs & didn't worked out :

[Rerun getToken(authorization) requests only on expiry - Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69011781/rerun-gettokenauthorization-requests-only-on-expiry-jmeter)

[How to handle Token expiration and regeneration during load test in JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68193833/how-to-handle-token-expiration-and-regeneration-during-load-test-in-jmeter).

Can anyone please suggest a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Get the token in one [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) which performs the authantication and set a delay for i.e. 11 hours and 30 minutes using [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler
2. Pass the token to the main Thread Group which is doing the endurance test by saving it into a JMeter Property in first Thread Group and reading it using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in second Thread Group

More information: [Using JMeter Variables With Multiple Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-variables)

Comment: 1. First Thread Group  which performm Authentication fired the token . suppose say if  we set delay of 60 secs .
2. Second Thread group which is the Main thread group executuion is not started till the completion of delay of 60 secs  .

3. Could you please tell how can we execute  Second thread group (i.e Main thread group) parallely.

Comment: You can use i.e. [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller) to wait until the token is available in the main Thread Group. Another option is using [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/).

Comment: As you said followed Inter-Thread Communication Plugin Approach .
Tried the following Test plan  .
1. Authentication Thread Group -> Generate Token API 1 HTTP Request Sampler -> Json Extractor ->BeanShell Assertion to store the token value -> jp@gc - Inter-Thread Communication PostProcessor used fifoput method  -> Flow Control Action to induce the delay for 11 hours 30 mins

Comment: 2. Main Thread Group -> API 2 HTTP Request Sampler -> ${__property(valueToPass)} in Header Manager fields -> jp@gc - Inter-Thread Communication PreProcessor .

Note : Main Thread Group has to run for 24 hours , then Authentication Thread Group has to issue the token at one time in the starting of the test & before expiry at 11 hours 45 mins it has to re-generate the token .

Above Approach didn't worked out for me , Could you please suggest any solution